# Checking internet connectivity in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, ping

This is perhaps a noob question.
I want to check the status of my internet connection like we do in Windows with "ping 172.16.0.1 -t" where we know there's connection if we get a reply. Is there a similar command in Ubuntu. A google search wasn't really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ping` from the terminal.  It should be available by default.  In Linux, your ping will continue to ping forever.  You can use the `-c` flag to limit the number of pings:

- `ping -c 1 172.16.0.1`

After reading the Windows Docs for `ping`, I understand the `-t` flag is to make the ping keep pinging forever.  As this is the default behavour of `ping` on Ubuntu, you would simply do the following:

- `ping 172.16.0.1`

Check `man ping` to read up on more options for `ping`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this command:
 `ping -c 4 172.16.0.1`
where number after c parameter means counts.

Comment: To use this command you have to open terminal via `ctrl+alt+t`